# Is there a deficient $N$ such that $\sqrt{D(N)} \mid A(N)$ holds, where $D(N)$ is the deficiency and $A(N)$ is the sum of the aliquot parts of $N$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum

Do there exist deficient numbers $N$ such that $$\sqrt{D(N)} \mid A(N)$$ holds, where $$D(N) = 2N - \sigma(N)$$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) and $$A(N) = \sigma(N) - N$$ is the [sum of aliquot parts](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $N$?

Comment: FWIW, the problem is equivalent to finding a deficient $N$ such that
$$\sqrt{D(N)} \text{ divides } \bigg(N - D(N) = A(N) \bigg),$$
or in simpler terms,
$$\sqrt{D(N)} \mid N.$$

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are infinitely many such numbers $N$.

Take $N=2^k$. Then, we get
$$\begin{align}\sigma(N)&=\sigma(2^k)=2^{k+1}-1\lt 2^{k+1}=2N
\\\\D(N)&=2^{k+1}-\sigma(2^k)=2^{k+1}-(2^{k+1}-1)=1\end{align}$$
from which
$$\sqrt{D(N)} \mid A(N)$$
follows.

---

Another example is $N=14$ which is not of the form $2^k$.

We get
$$\begin{align}\sigma(14)&=(1+2)(1+7)=24\lt 2\times 14
\\\\D(N)&=D(14)=28-\sigma(14)=28-24=4
\\\\A(N)&=\sigma(14)-14=24-14=10\end{align}$$
from which
$$\sqrt{D(N)} \mid A(N)$$
follows.